# Узнать соседние позиции в рейтинге

Tags: sql

Имеется таблица accounts, примерно с такими данными:

```
name | c1| c2    
test1| 5 | 0    
test2| 1 | 6    
test3| 5 | 11    
test4| 0 | 0    
...
```

Мне нужно было получить позицию аккаунта в рейтинге по сумме двух колонок `c1` и `c2`.

Сделал это так:

```
SELECT 
   name, (c1 + c2) as total,
   (SELECT count(*)+1 FROM accounts WHERE (c1 + c2) > total) as position 
FROM accounts WHERE name = 'test2'
```

Получится аккаунт `test2` будет на втором месте. Как теперь можно получить аккаунты, которые стоят на 1 и 3 месте (то есть рядом с этим аккаунтом)?

Answer (score 2):

Так будет на большинстве SQL диалектов работать:

```
with ranked as (
    select name, (c1+c2) as total, dense_rank () over (order by (c1+c2) desc) rnk
    from accounts a 
) select r.name, r.total, r.rnk, p.name "lower ranked", n.name "higher ranked"  
from ranked r
left join ranked p on p.rnk = r.rnk+1
left join ranked n on n.rnk = r.rnk-1
order by r.rnk
```

Результат:

```
NAME          TOTAL        RNK lower    higher  
-------- ---------- ---------- -------- --------
test3            16          1 test2            
test2             7          2 test1    test3   
test1             5          3 test4    test2   
test4             0          4          test1
```

Рабочий пример на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=826156f3f5ce7d06bb85f145a87d729a), там же можно попробовать с другим брэндом БД.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте оконные функции.

Из таблицы, которую вы получаете после подсчетов, это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
SELECT  
    name, 
    LAG(name) OVER(ORDER BY position) prev_name, 
    LEAD(name) OVER(ORDER BY position) next_name
FROM ...
```

Этим вы получите название аккаунта, который стоит на позиции перед текущим:

```
LAG(name) OVER(ORDER BY position)
```

А через `LEAD` - следующим. У граничных аккаунтов будет `NULL` в `prev_name/next_name` соответственно.

Comment: если диалект поддерживает данные оконные функции